# Use Google Analytics Audience on My Own Site

Tags: google-analytics

I want to target heavy users of my site with some custom UI elements.

Google Analytics is good at building audiences based on their behavior. For example, I can build audiences who visit the site at least 50 times a month. Or maybe those that have up or down voted something and also had at least 5 sessions this month.

When a user visits our site, in the browser I want to be able to do something like:

```
if (ga.audiences.inclues('myHeavyUserAudience')) {
  $('.some-cool-ui').show()
}
```

Ideally I could define audiences on Google Analytics and then evaluate on the client if the particular user is in that audience. The alternative here is to track the relevant info myself in a cookie on the client. That is less than ideal because:

- Some of the metrics are monthly figures and would require a while to 'spin up'
- I may want to adjust the audience definitions going forward and would be convenient to update directly from GA

So can I access a user's audiences or segments from the client?

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics doesn't expose created audiences to 2nd and 3rd parties so you cannot identify your visitor as belonging to some audience or segment. You need to have your own customer identification and tracking system to do that.
You may connect your system in some way with google analytics based on some IDs provided at your side and Google Analytics clientId / userID and custom dimensions but this is not a suggested use and Analytics doesn't fit into this task ideally.
There are some others audience management tools that could help you better. Kissmetrics and Mixpanel are what pops up to my mind but there are many others.
there are few links if you want to deeper understand the background of users IDs in Analytics and possible use but, again, there's no explicit method to evaluate on the client if the particular user is in that audience:

- [User-ID reference](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850?hl=en)
- [Custom dimensions & metrics](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! User IDs would help me connect users to GA data, but still wouldn't help me extract GA segment/audience data on the client side. I suppose I could export User ID lists then from GA and check against those on the client....

Comment: you may put UserID or any other ID to custom dimension and later use this with Core Reporting API to fetch some metrics and dimensions for a particular user and in that way to check if this fits some audience condition. But this is not what GA is suited for since you'll quickly get into API limits or some processing issues.